# How to filter dropdown list in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to filter a dropdown list of departments based on a `DepartmentType` value. The `DepartmentType` has a key in the `Department` class.

I am using Entity Framework.

Here is my `Department` class:

```
public partial class Department
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        this.Skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
    }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Enter Department")]
    [Display(Name ="Department")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public Nullable<int> DepartmentTypeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Status")]
    public Nullable<bool> DepartmrntStatus { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Type")]
    public virtual DepartmentType DepartmentType { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my `DepartmentType` class

```
public partial class DepartmentType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public DepartmentType()
    {
        this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }

    public int DepartmentTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Enter Department Type")]
    [Display (Name = "Department Type")]
    public string DepartmentTypeName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code in my controller which is populating the departments:

```cs
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
```

This is populating all of the departments. I want to filter it by `DepartmentType`. something like:

```cs
ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName")
//.where DepartmentTypeName (of my departmentType class) == "My dept type name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know whether its effecient or not but thats how i have done it

```
var deptType =(from Id in db.DepartmentTypes
                          where Id.DepartmentTypeName == "Employee Departmrnt"
                          select Id.DepartmentTypeId).ToArray();
        int deptTypeId = 0;
        foreach (var i in deptType)
        {
            deptTypeId =Convert.ToInt32(i);
        }
        var departmentId = (from Id in db.Departments
                            where Id.DepartmentTypeId == deptTypeId
                            select new
                            {
                                Id.DepartmentId,
                                Id.DepartmentName
                            }
                           ).ToList();
        ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(departmentId, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
```